# How to open a pop up window on clicking on list view items?

Tags: android

I want a list view in which on clicking on each row of list view a pop up window should open.In that pop up window I want a list view only.

Please suggest me how to do it.As I m new to android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use Dialog with listView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code inside `onItemClickListener`

```
  final CharSequence[] items = { "Mango", "Banana", "Apple" };
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Select Fruit");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the onitemclick method of the listview do this:

```
Dialog dialog= new Dialog(this);
LayoutInflater inflater  = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflate.inflate(R.layout.view, null);
dialog.setContentView(v);
dialog.show();
```

the layout R.layout.view can contain the listview. 
Use an adapter to set items into the listview.

And in order to access the lstview use

```
view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Open pop up window in **OnItemClickListener** of ListView like this:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
      // show pop up window
    }
});
```

To show pop up window refer this link, [Set own layout in popup window in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153651/set-own-layout-in-popup-window-in-android)

Design a layout accordingly you want to show in the pop up and set in pop up window.

Or as a second option you can  show a custom dialog onItemClick.

Answer (score 0):

try expandableListActivity to show your reqirement.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html