# how to open a popup window on clicking on the list view items

Tags: android

I need a listview in which on clicking on each row a popup window should be opened.

In that popup window I need to display item from listview.

How to open a popup window with item?

Comment: In the Pop Up Window what exactly do you need to display?

Comment: actually i have project of multiple list views that is 3 listviews attached to one adopter  now is if i click on items in the list view i need pop up with having items in list view with check boxes

Comment: Okay. So, you have a ListView and when an item is clicked you want display a Pop up Dialog with Check boxes on it, which is again a list of items?

Comment: yes , by selecting check boxes i have to disable item

Comment: Are those Check boxes or Radio Buttons? Because if you use Check boxes there could be multiple selections.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a pop up window on clicking on list view items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563221/how-to-open-a-pop-up-window-on-clicking-on-list-view-items)

Comment: yes, i need check oxes only

Answer (score 0):

You have to try karan`s answer

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogActivity.this);
builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
builderSingle.setTitle("Select One Name:-");

final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        DialogActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
arrayAdapter.add("Hardik");
arrayAdapter.add("Archit");
arrayAdapter.add("Jignesh");
arrayAdapter.add("Umang");
arrayAdapter.add("Gatti");

builderSingle.setNegativeButton(
        "cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

builderSingle.setAdapter(
        arrayAdapter,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
                AlertDialog.Builder builderInner = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        DialogActivity.this);
                builderInner.setMessage(strName);
                builderInner.setTitle("Your Selected Item is");
                builderInner.setPositiveButton(
                        "Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(
                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builderInner.show();
            }
        });
builderSingle.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view);
popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup);
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
popupMenu.show();
```

`view` is the view clicked and will be used as the anchor point.