# Create pop up with a list of options like Youtube App

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, dialog, material-design

I am trying to create a view similar to the Youtube app as shown below:

[image]

On click I will open a dialog as shown below:

[image]

Is there any view or library that is already build by android that can help me create it or do I need to create it by myself?

I tried searching it but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way I have managed using

> [**`Dialogs`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs)

- A dialog is a small window that prompts the user to make a decision or enter additional information. A dialog does not fill the screen and is normally used for modal events that require users to take an action before they can proceed.

> [**`RecyclerView`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView)

- A flexible view for providing a limited window into a large data set.

**SAMPLE CODE**

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    RelativeLayout myRelativeLayout;
    TextView tvText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout);
        tvText = findViewById(R.id.tvText);

        myRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showCustomDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showCustomDialog() {

        final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(this);
        myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
        DataAdapter dataAdapter;
        ArrayList<DataModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        Button btnCancel;

        // setting custom layout in out dialog
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);

        // findViewById for views inside dialog
        myRecyclerView = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.MyRecyclerView);
        btnCancel = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

        // programatically setting hight and witdh of dialog
        Window window = myDialog.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        // setting gravity of dialog so it will diaply in the center of screen
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        // setting TRANSPARENT Background to myDialog to display myDialog with rounded corner
        myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        // adding data in to arrayList

        arrayList.add(new DataModel("Very Small", false));
        arrayList.add(new DataModel("Small", false));
        arrayList.add(new DataModel("Normal", true));
        arrayList.add(new DataModel("Large", true));
        arrayList.add(new DataModel("Very Large", true));

        // using DataAdapter.OnItemClickListener() getting result which item is selected in recyclerview
        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(this, arrayList, new DataAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DataModel item, int position) {
                // setting result in a textview when user select recyclerview item
                tvText.setText(item.getName());
            }
        });

        // setting LayoutManager in myRecyclerView
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        // setting Adapter( in myRecyclerView
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        // click listner for btnCancel to dismiss myDialog
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        // used for display Dialog
        myDialog.show();
    }


}
```

> layout.activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/myRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Language"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="Deafult" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> layout.custom_dialog_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Text Size"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/MyRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="270dp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:paddingStart="50dp"
            android:paddingEnd="50dp"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#00b7ff" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> DataAdapter

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<DataModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final OnItemClickListener listener;


    public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataModel> arrayList, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    private int lastCheckedPosition = -1;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        // here i'm changing the state of radio button based on user select
        viewHolder.radioImage.setChecked(position == lastCheckedPosition);

        viewHolder.tvTextName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());

        // this is condition is used to hide line from thr last recyclerview item
        if (position == arrayList.size()-1) {
            viewHolder.bottomLine.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.bottomLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(DataModel item, int position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View bottomLine;
        RadioButton radioImage;
        TextView tvTextName;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            bottomLine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bottomLine);
            radioImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioImage);
            tvTextName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTextName);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    arrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(true);
                    lastCheckedPosition = getAdapterPosition();

                    // getting result when user selecte radio button in your activity
                    listener.onItemClick(arrayList.get(lastCheckedPosition), lastCheckedPosition);

                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

> layout.custom_row_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTextName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        tools:text="TextName" />


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic__unchecked_radio_button" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvTextName"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> ic__unchecked_radio_button.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.42,0 -8,-3.58 -8,-8s3.58,-8 8,-8 8,3.58 8,8 -3.58,8 -8,8z"/>
</vector>
```

> ic_checked_radio_button.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,7c-2.76,0 -5,2.24 -5,5s2.24,5 5,5 5,-2.24 5,-5 -2.24,-5 -5,-5zM12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.42,0 -8,-3.58 -8,-8s3.58,-8 8,-8 8,3.58 8,8 -3.58,8 -8,8z"/>
</vector>
```

> round_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <!-- this one is ths color of the Rounded Button -->
    <solid android:color="#476e6e6e" />
    <!-- this one is used to set radius of the Rounded Button -->
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
</shape>
```

> **OUTPUT**

Please check this video(output of above code) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGf-30Oh8OM

> Screen-Shots

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

> **NOTE**

You can also use [**`PopupWindow`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow) to achieve this

- This class represents a popup window that can be used to display an arbitrary view. The popup window is a floating container that appears on top of the current activity.

Here are some good article for it

- [Android PopupWindow Example](https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2017/07/android-popupwindow-example.html)
- [How to create a popup window (PopupWindow) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944987/how-to-create-a-popup-window-popupwindow-in-android)
- [Android Popup Window Example](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2016/01/android-popup-window-example.html)
- [Set own layout in popup window in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153651/set-own-layout-in-popup-window-in-android)
- [Custom Pop Up Window with Android Studio](https://awsrh.blogspot.com/2017/10/custom-pop-up-window-with-android-studio.html)

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @NNilesh Rathod is also a way around (great for providing the codes and styles), while answer by @J. Jefferson gives you system default dialog fragment.
As far as the image provide, it's the Bottom Sheet Dialog rather than Dialog.

The good way is to extend [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment) and [BottomSheetDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment) in your fragment class.

Examples to proceed ahead
[Android Hive](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/), 
[Medium](https://medium.com/@kosta.palash/using-bottomsheetdialogfragment-with-material-design-guideline-f9814c39b9fc).
You can find more as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DialogFragment](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-dialogfragment) provided by Android. It works just like a regular Fragment where you can create custom layouts. The differences are that you extend DialogFragment and override the necessary methods to create it. When the Fragment is shown, it will display over your layout as you want it. The link provided is an in depth tutorial with multiple examples on how to set it up, change styles, sizes, titles, layouts etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid fragements and all the headaches that they provide , have a look at this cool [SlidingLayout](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library. Use it as per instructions and will get desired result:)